# Use of dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a concept learning programs, where I need to convert from index to the name of categories.

For example:

```
# binary concept learning
# candidate eliminaton learning algorithm
import numpy as np
import csv

def main():
    d1={0:'0', 1:'Japan', 2: 'USA', 3: 'Korea', 4: 'Germany', 5:'?'}
    d2={0:'0', 1:'Honda', 2: 'Chrysler', 3: 'Toyota', 4:'?'}
    d3={0:'0', 1:'Blue', 2:'Green', 3: 'Red', 4:'White', 5:'?'}
    d4={0:'0', 1:1970,2:1980, 3:1990, 4:2000, 5:'?'}
    d5={0:'0', 1:'Economy', 2:'Sports', 3:'SUV', 4:'?'}

    a=[0,1,2,3,4]
    print a

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

So `[0,1,2,3,4]` should convert to `['0', 'Honda', 'Green', '1990', '?']`. What is the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have different dictionaries and use indexes as key?

Comment: each column corresnding to one category. For example, a[0] is where the car is from, a[1] is the manufacturer, etc...

Comment: a[] is a list containing 0,1,2,3,4 it is not dictionary. Please clarify your question

Comment: If you are using the `dicts` like `lists` or `tuples`, why even bother with `dicts`?

Comment: yea Dzung. You arent using dictionaries to their fullest extent. check this out `dict1 = {'manufacturer': 'honda'}` ; `dict1['manufacturer'] ` It outputs the word 'honda' and its easy to remember and you dont have to deal with confusing indexes!

Comment: Is there a rule of what you want to do? For example it is seen as you are trying to take some kind of taking diagonal elements. İs that your definite rule? This is unclear point in your question

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a basic dictionary crash course:

this is a proper dictionary:

```
>>>d1 = { 'tires' : 'yoko', 'manufacturer': 'honda', 'vtec' : 'no' }
```

You can call invidual things in the dictionary easily:

```
>>>d1['tires']
'yoko'
>>>d1['vtec'] = 'yes' #mad vtec yo
>>>d1['vtec']
'yes'
```

Dictionaries are broken up into two different sections, the key and the value

```
testDict = {'key':'value'}
```

You were using a dictionary the exact same way as a list:

```
>>>test = {0:"thing0", 1:"thing1"} #dictionary
>>>test[0]
'thing0'
```

which is pretty much the exact same as saying

```
>>>test = ['thing0','thing1'] #list
>>>test[0]
'thing0'
```

in your particular case, you may want to either format your dictionaries properly ( i would suggest something like `masterdictionary = {'country': ['germany','france','USA','japan], 'manufacturer': ['honda','ferrarri','hoopty'] } etcetera` because you could call each individual item you wanted a lot easier

with that same dictionary:

```
>>>masterdictionary['country'][1]
'germany'
```

which is
    `dictionaryName['key'][iteminlistindex]`

of course there is nothing preventing you from putting dictionaries as values inside of dictionaries.... inside values of other dictionaries...

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
data = [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5]
print [d[key] for key, d in zip(a, data)]
```

The function [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) can be used to combine to iterables; lists in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the answer to your direct question, but you may wish to consider re-structuring the data. To me, the following makes a lot more sense, and will enable you to more easily index into it for what you asked, and for any possible later queries:

```
from pprint import pprint

items = [[el.get(i, '?') for el in (d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)] for i in range(6)]
pprint(items)

[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['Japan', 'Honda', 'Blue', 1970, 'Economy'],
 ['USA', 'Chrysler', 'Green', 1980, 'Sports'],
 ['Korea', 'Toyota', 'Red', 1990, 'SUV'],
 ['Germany', '?', 'White', 2000, '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list of dicts `d = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]`, and then a list comprehension:

```
[d[i][key] for i, key in enumerate(a)]
```

To make the whole thing more readable, use nested dictionaries - each of your dictionaries seems to represent something you could give a more descriptive name than d1 or d2:

```
data = {'country': {0: 'Japan', 1: 'USA' ... }, 'brand': {0: 'Honda', ...}, ...}
car = {'country': 1, 'brand': 2 ... }
[data[attribute][key] for attribute, key in car.items()]
```

Note this would not necessarily be in order if that is important, though I think there is an ordered dictionary type.

As suggested by the comment, a dictionary with contiguous integers as keys can be replaced by a list:

```
data = {'country': ['Japan', 'USA', ...], 'brand': ['Honda', ...], ...}
```

Comment: Don't use a dictionary with numbered keys, that's just stupid. This is the whole point of a list, which supports numerical indexing by itself.

Comment: That's how the data was stored in the original question. Though yes, in this case lists for the data would make more sense. Calling an answer stupid doesn't help anything.

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was a little strongly worded.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep d1, d2, etc. as is:

```
newA = [locals()["d%d"%(i+1)][a_value] for i,a_value in enumerate(a)]
```

Pretty ugly, and fragile, but it should work with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a dictionary for this at all. Lists in python automatically support indexing.

```
def main():

    d1=['0','Japan','USA','Korea','Germany',"?"]
    d2=['0','Honda','Chrysler','Toyota','?']
    d3=['0','Blue','Green','Red','White','?']
    d4=['0', 1970,1980,1990,2000,'?']
    d5=['0','Economy','Sports','SUV','?']
    ds = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5] #This holds all your lists

    #This is what range is for
    a=range(5)
    #Find the nth index from the nth list, seems to be what you want
    print [ds[n][n] for n in a] #This is a list comprehension, look it up.
```